# AKS pods are not working ErrPullback error comes always

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am learning azure kubernetes service and trying to deploy an simple app to AKS. I upload the image to ACR. That is a very simple app of only one html file. I will write down all the files
My HTMl file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple</title>
</head>
    <body style="background-color:rgb(212, 240, 234);">
        <h1>Simple Application</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My Docker file is as below. only two lines.

```
FROM nginx

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My deployment file is again simple

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1-nginx
          image: simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-loadbalancer-service
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: app1-nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

When I deploy my yaml file. It has following outcomes.

```
➜  simple kubectl get no
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE     VERSION
aks-agentpool-42782457-vmss000000   Ready    agent   8m38s   v1.23.8
aks-agentpool-42782457-vmss000001   Ready    agent   8m52s   v1.23.8
```

But when I check the status of pods it shows this

```
➜  simple kubectl get po
NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
app1-nginx-deployment-7576f5c78b-j59cf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (13s ago)   20s
```

When i tried to go in details for my pods always I am getting this response.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m59s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/app1-nginx-deployment-7576f5c78b-j59cf to aks-agentpool-42782457-vmss000001
  Normal   Pulled     7m54s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple" in 4.199038838s
  Normal   Pulled     7m52s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple" in 146.207115ms
  Normal   Pulled     7m37s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple" in 238.000761ms
  Normal   Created    7m10s (x4 over 7m54s)   kubelet            Created container app1-nginx
  Normal   Pulled     7m10s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple" in 157.27582ms
  Normal   Started    7m9s (x4 over 7m54s)    kubelet            Started container app1-nginx
  Normal   Pulling    6m29s (x5 over 7m58s)   kubelet            Pulling image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple"
  Normal   Pulled     6m29s                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "simplecc24.azurecr.io/simple" in 178.361528ms
  Warning  BackOff    2m53s (x25 over 7m51s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Please help me out in this problem.

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: what to specifically look for in logs ?